# How to check if an element is on top of page

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have a testcase that checks when user clicks a buton, the title should scroll up to top of page. But by default there is a header. So the title should come below that. How can we check that. Please help

Comment: Your code trials , HTML code if any.

Comment: element.getBoundingClientRect() might be useful

Answer (score 1):

The following is very "long hand" approach, but it has worked very successfully for me in the past.

You can extract location and size via Selenium commands for both objects.  Then you can calculate the area of the screen the header is in, and compare it to the area of the screen the title appears.

If those areas overlap, you can say that the title is hidden by the header.

Here is an example as an RSpec Matcher;

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_within do |reference_object|

  @reference_object_location = reference_object.location
  @reference_object_size = reference_object.size

  match do |relative_object|

    @relative_object_location = relative_object.location
    @relative_object_size = relative_object.size

    relative_x_max = @relative_object_location.x + @relative_object_size.width
    relative_x_min = @relative_object_location.x
    relative_y_max = @relative_object_location.y + @relative_object_size.height
    relative_y_min = @relative_object_location.y

    reference_x_max = @reference_object_location.x + @reference_object_size.width
    reference_x_min = @reference_object_location.x
    reference_y_max = @reference_object_location.y + @reference_object_size.height
    reference_y_min = @reference_object_location.y

    relative_x_max <= reference_x_max && relative_y_max <= reference_y_max &&
    relative_x_min >= reference_x_min && relative_y_min >= reference_y_min

  end
```

As I said, not pretty!